# Seam carving energy calculation method and seam finding

Tags: c#, image-processing, path-finding, seam-carving

I am trying to implement a program like [intelligent scissors](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-iscissors.html). The difference it will not follow the edges, but it will be tend to pass between two edges.

I found seam carving useful for this purpose. What I need to do is calculate the energy of an image and find seams on it. But I couldn't find how to implement it in [the paper](http://www.win.tue.nl/~wstahw/2IV00/seamcarving.pdf) and couldn't find an implementation either. Can anybody recommend an easier source that I can understand and implement? or an implementation which I can try and see wheather it will work for my purpose or not?

Comment: I doubt you'll find many sample written in C#. If you google for "seam carving matlab", you get a lot of hits, though.

Answer (score 2):

The best implementation of CAIR I've found [is here](http://sites.google.com/site/brainrecall/cair). The link includes a pretty simple and straightforward explanation of how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 1):

Does this article on Wikipedia help at all? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving

Comment: No. I am looking for a detailed explanation of algorithm actually.